# How do I pass additional variables to defaultLayout in a Yesod handler?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I want to do something similar to what I'm trying below. Seems like I need to learn more about Monads. Any pointers?
I did use `yesod init` to get going and `yesod add-handler` to create the handler.

In `Handler/Hello.hs`:

```
getHelloR :: Handler Html
getHelloR = do
    let hello = "Hello World"
    defaultLayout $ do
        $(widgetFile "hello")
```

In `templates/hello.hamlet`:

```
<h1>Test
<p>#{hello}
```

The error I'm getting when running `cabal-dev install && yesod --dev devel`
is:

```
Handler/Hello.hs:9:11:
    Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraints:
      (Data.String.IsString a0)
        arising from a use of `hello' at Handler/Hello.hs:9:11-28
      (blaze-markup-0.5.1.5:Text.Blaze.ToMarkup a0)
        arising from a use of `toHtml' at Handler/Hello.hs:9:11-28
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In the first argument of `toHtml', namely `hello'
    In the first argument of `asWidgetT . toWidget', namely
      `toHtml hello'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: (asWidgetT . toWidget) (toHtml hello)
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  Did you initialize using "yesod init"?  If you do, it will create a skeleton that should work (if not show us the error), and you can then morph that to your code (it will be pretty close to what you wrote already, except that the .hamlet file will be more fleshed out, but you can remove everything from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What this error message means is "I know that the `hello` variable is some kind of IsString instance, but I don't know which one." In other words, `hello` would be of type `String`, `Text`, `Html`, or something else, but the compiler can't figure it out based on the information you're providing. The easiest was to solve this is to add an explicit type signature, e.g.:

```
let hello :: String
    hello = "Hello World"
```

This is a somewhat common issue that arises when using `OverloadedStrings`.